# What is the efficient way to query inherited object with hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, entitymanager

I have the following classes:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class A {}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public abstract class B extends A {
    @Id
    private Long Id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ONE_B")
public class One extends B {}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TWO_B")
public class Two extends B {}

@Entity
@Table(name = "THREE_B")
public class Three extends B {}
```

If I do an entityManager.find(B.class, id), then Hibernate generates an extraordinary query to check every single, which is not efficient. How this can be handled in the most efficient way without any additional param/column?

With a NamedQuery to get the table name, which contains the inherited B object?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know at coding time what type an entity is of, then Hibernate does not know either. If you ask Hibernate to query for an object of type `B`, then it has to join all tables of the subclasses to fetch all the possible data, in order to initialize the entity object correctly. There is nothing you can do to improve this situation, except for changing the code to query the entity class that you expect e.g. `One`, `Two` or `Three`. But even then, obviously Hibernate will have to join at least the tables of the parent classes to acquire all the data.

If you don't want joins to happen, then change your data model and use discriminator based single table inheritance.

Apart from all that, how do you know this is not efficient? Did you try out different approaches and **measured** that they were more efficient? If so, then please report these findings. If you are just assuming things, only **measuring** will be able to help you know for sure.

You know, after all, relational database are pretty good at joins, since that is their bread and butter. If something is slow, that might be due to missing indexes.